# Use Simple Mic and Speaker at a time Live

Tags: laptop, speakers, microphone

I was thinking to use my mic and speakers together as a Live scenarion.

I am having laptop (Dell Latitude E6400).

First of all is it possible??

If you don't got my point then please something in detail as comment. Since I don't know the exact terms/words to use for them.

Comment: It isn't about using the right terms.  It is about being able to detail what you want to do.  You want to use the Mic and Speakers together at the same time... well, here's an example of that.  What if you were playing a video game, and using the built-in voice chat functions?  That would require hearing people speak to you, as well as being able to speak to them, thus using the speakers and mic at the same time.  Or using TeamSpeak, or C3, or XFire, or one of the many others like them.  Again, using the speakers and mic at the same time.  Yes it is possible, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks sir, for information. I think you have missed link to add in comment.

Comment: No, I had no links to provide.  I am asking **you** to further detail what it is exactly that you want to do.  As it stands, that model laptop had an option to come with a microphone (most likely if it came with a webcam as well).  So, if you *have* a microphone, then yes... you can use both the mic and the speakers at the same time.  It all depends on what you want to do... which is what I am asking you to detail.

Comment: Actually I wanted, How to do that? I wanted some link/Steps.

Comment: At this point, I suspect that language is a barrier we cannot overcome.  In order to give you steps on how to use the mic and speakers at the same time, I would need to know what **programs** you intend to use the mic and speakers together with.  Otherwise, it would just be a matter of finding the speaker icon near the clock in the task bar, and right clicking on it to bring up the Mixer panel... and then making sure the microphone is not muted and has levels.  In fact, unmuting the mic would probably create feedback, proving it was working with the speakers.